# HTML dropdown hangs when option chosen, then closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am making some edits [on a site](https://realdatelosangeles.com/register/) and the zip code dropdown hangs when I choose a selection. I am not sure why; I created a [mirror of the site](https://realdatethecity.com/register/) and the mirror sites works fine. Any idea of why that would be? All the code should be exact, so I'm a little confused on why it hangs on one site and not the other.

The js code that edits a lot of this page is found [here](https://realdatelosangeles.com/wp-content/themes/sweetdate-child/js/registration.js).

Comment: Maybe put some more details? It's working fine for me (Chrome  52.0.2743.116).

Comment: Post the relevant code, remove the URLs to the sites.

Comment: @JordanS - it doesn't hang on either site?

Comment: Please post your html. Not site link